# cant get json data to go through server to run through functions

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongoose, server

I'm using postman to run authentication data through my database but when i try it tells me it doesn't see any of the fields I've asked for.

i ran data through postman but when it runs into my code it tells me it doesn't see expected fields

my server file

```
const express = require("express");
const { chats } = require("./data/data")
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
const { authMiddleware } = require('./util/auth');
const path = require('path');
const colors = require("colors")
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes")

const db = require('./config/connection.js');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get('/',  (req,res) => {
   res.send("API is Running"); 
})



app.use('/api/user',userRoutes)

db.once('open', () => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`API server running on port ${PORT}!` .blue.bold);
    });
  });
```

my user controller

```
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const generateToken = require("../config/generateToken");

const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, pic } = req.body;
    
     if (!name || !email || !password) {
      res.status(400);
      throw new Error("Please Enter all the Fields");
    }
  
    const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });
  
    if (userExists) {
      res.status(400);
      throw new Error("User already exists");
    }
  
    const user = await User.create({
      name,
      email,
      password,
      pic,
    });
  
    if (user) {
      res.status(201).json({
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
        pic: user.pic,
        token: generateToken(user._id),
      });
    } else {
      res.status(400);
      throw new Error("User not found");
    }
    
  });
 
module.exports = { registerUser }
```

i run this data through

```
{
    "name": "examplename",
    "email": example"e@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

this is the response i get

```
Error: Please Enter all the Fields
    at C:\Users\doubl\OneDrive\Desktop\Messege Testing\server\Controllers\userControllers.js:9:13
    at asyncUtilWrap (C:\Users\doubl\OneDrive\Desktop\Messege Testing\node_modules\express-async-handler\index.js:3:20)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\doubl\OneDrive\Desktop\Messege Testing\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\doubl\OneDrive\Desktop\Messege Testing\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\doubl\OneDrive\Desktop\Messege Testing\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\doubl\OneDrive\Desktop\Messege Testing\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\doubl\OneDrive\Desktop\Messege Testing\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\doubl\OneDrive\Desktop\Messege Testing\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\doubl\OneDrive\Desktop\Messege Testing\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\doubl\OneDrive\Desktop\Messege Testing\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
```

Comment: What's inside the **userRoutes** file? The code that you've posted doesn't show where and how the `registerUser` function is used.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the model there is a required field of pic that's why getting error make it optional or add a new variable in data field pic: "xyz....."